# what' the difference between Indicator Constraint "->" and "<->" in .lp format file

Tags: constraints, cplex, indicator

I am completely new to CPLEX and I am trying to solve a problem with CPLEX 12.9. I don't known what's the difference between Indicator Constraint  "->" and "<->". Does it mean that "->" equals to "if... then" and "<->" equals to "If and only if...then"?

the example is shown as follow:

```
 i1:  x14 = 1 <-> x(0)  = 0
 i2:  x13 = 1 -> x14  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

yes -> means if then and <-> means equivalent

For example if you write in OPL

```
dvar int x;
dvar boolean b;

subject to
{
  b==(x==1);
}
```

then in the lp file you will see

```
 i1: x1 = 1 <-> x  = 1
```

and if you write

```
dvar int x;
dvar boolean b;

subject to
{
  (b==1)=>(x==1);
}
```

then in the lp file you will see

```
i2: x1 = 1 -> x3  = 1
```